# Windows system password hashed - see which hash is used

Tags: passwords, hash, windows

How can I know / see if my windows is using NTML, LM, NTML2 for its user account passwords?

What is the standard today, in windows systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently windows uses NTLMv2 to store the password, but for backward compatibility some system uses LM hashes. Now it is recommended by the Microsoft to not to use LM method to store the password because of its weakness towards brute force attacks. If you want to see currently which method is used then you have to navigate to  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA. You will see the entry named NoLMhash with the DWORD value 1. It means LM hash storage is disabled in your system.

On the same location you can see the name LmCompatibilityLevel edit that and see the value associated with it and if the value is 0, 1 or 2 then force the system to use only NTLMv2 by changing that value to 3.

If you are in the LAN then you can check which method is used by your system to communicate to the servers by capturing the packet using any ethereal tool i.e tcpdump, wireshark in the network.

[Refer this link to understand the compatibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960646.aspx)

Comment: And what does that link say?

Comment: The link describes about the compatibility between host and server authentication.